# Best way to build word from letters

Tags: c++

I need to build words from the alphabet by picking letters individually. What is the best way of doing this (and by best I mean fastest)? Currently I do this:

```
string alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string word;
word = alpha.substr(9,1) + alpha.substr(6,1) + alpha.substr(13,1) + alpha.substr(13,1) + alpha.substr(16,1) + alpha.substr(1,1) + alpha.substr(1,1);
```

would spell "Hello  " and then I erase possible whitespaces with:

```
word.erase(remove_if( word.begin(), word.end(), ::isspace), word.end() );
```

I m new to c++, more of a c# background. Is this a good way of doing this? Or should I use char[]? or possibly even machine representation? This cant really be the best way as a simple foreach loop on List in c# executes faster...

Comment: Define "best". For readability purposes, this looks an OK solution, although you don't need but the first `substr` (the rest could be simply `alpha[6]`, etc.). Now as for "as a simple foreach loop on List in c# executes faster..." – And does it matter? Is this a bottleneck in your program? Did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: Try `word.append(alpha[9]).append(alpha[6]).append(alpha[13])`

Comment: The fastest would be to skip string alpha entirely. In c/c++ the number you already have IS a letter. If you already know each letter, why bother getting it again from a string class?

Comment: @frymode: is this the same as (only in literals) what mike suggested in his answer? i.e. word += alpha[9];

Comment: @KennyOstrom: seems logical. but how would that work? store all number representations in double[] and then convert to word after after letters are chosen?

Comment: @nik: No, Kenny means `std::string word = "Hello "` which is fairly quick ;)

Comment: ah ok, but hello was just an example, if I knew the word it would be simple I agree

Comment: @nik yes, but with chaining syntax

Comment: @nik: The chaining doesn't make it faster. What does make a difference is the `.reserve(7)` in Mike's answer or the direct initialization to length 7 in mine. Growing a string in 7 steps of 1 character may cause 6 copies of the initial prefixes, copying 21 characters in total (1+2+3+4+5+6).

Comment: You are starting with an index for each letter. If you have a fixed character set with contiguous letters (like ascii), then you don't have to look up what letter 9 is, you can compute it directly by checking to see if it is in the letter range, then basically typecast int to char by adding ('a'-2). This is way too fancy, nonportable and error prone unless speed is REALLY important.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: It's not even that fast because of the check. An array lookup, with a sufficiently large array and a range-restricted array index is branchless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way of doing this (and by best I mean fastest)?

It's probably fastest to:

- reserve enough space for all the letters you want;
- pick out individual characters (not substrings of length 1) and append these.

which would look like

```
string word;
word.reserve(7);
word += alpha[9];
// ...
word += alpha[1];
```

This will involve at most a single memory allocation. Your method creates several intermediate `string` objects which might, or might not, involve more allocations, depending on how `string` is implemented.

As always when optimising, measure to make sure what your doing is a worthwhile optimisation.

> Or should I use `char[]`?

If the size (or at least an upper bound) is known at compile time, then that would allow you to avoid dynamic allocation altogether. If it isn't, then you can't.

You can remove spaces in a similar way; since the array size is fixed, you'll need to keep track of the end of the valid data:

```
char word[MAX_SIZE];       // enough space for MAX_SIZE
char * end = word + size;  // "size" is the actual number of valid characters

// Remove spaces from the range [word,end)
// and update end to point to the end of the remaining letters
end = remove_if(word, end, ::isspace);
```

Comment: much better! thank you. If say I want to build a word with at most 9 letters, should I use char[9] over string? would I still be able to remove whitespaces in the same way?

Comment: @nik: You can't remove chars from a `char[9]`, that is to say it will always stay a `char[9]`. `std::string::size()`  can vary.

Comment: You can remove whitespace, although in a different way. A word of at most 9 letters would be char[10], and it ends at the '\0' character.

Comment: @nik: You can use `remove_if` to remove spaces, moving the remaining characters to the front of the array. The array will still be the same size (since that's fixed); the function will return a pointer to one past the end of the remaining characters.

Comment: if I use word.clear() do I have to follow by word.reserve(7) or does clear not wipe this out?

Comment: @nik: You should call `reserve` again. It's not specified whether `clear` preserves the capacity.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the fastest is likely

```
string alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string word {alpha[9], alpha[5], alpha[13], alpha[13], alpha[16], alpha[0], alpha[0]};
```

That is to say: construct word directly as a string of the right length, picking just the characters you need.

Fast ways to remove a certain char which can occur more than once are unfortunately not simple, you'll need to write code yourself:

```
std::string copy;
copy.reserve(word.size()); // Somewhat too much, but OK
for (char c: word) if (c!= ' ') copy.append(c);
```

or

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i)
  if(word[i] != ' ') word[j++] = word[i];
word.resize(j);
```

Comment: Err... `std::erase(std::remove(begin(word), end(word), ' '), end(word));`?

Comment: @jrok: Also an option, although the [complexity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) appears to be expressed in terms of characters checked, not moved.

Answer (score 0):

To get an individual letter, you want alphabet[9], not alphabet.substr(9,1)
because the former gets that letter
and the later constructs a new string and copies that letter into it.

Comment: string::at(size_t pos) does the same thing, but also checks for a bad index, for which it will throw out_of_range exception

Comment: if I rewrite this to alpha[x] + alpha[x], i get some odd results and execution is not faster at all

Comment: @nik: because + promotes the characters to integer values, and adds the numerical values (!)

Comment: @nik: Indeed, adding two characters gives a number (the sum of the character values) not a string. Try `word += alpha[x]` to append to the string.

Comment: great thanks. Man, c# does a lot of stuff for you which you dont even think about....